# Type.forName fails on @testVisible private inner class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I recently wrote a class to schedule any number of jobs for execution, and was working on making a test class for the class. Instead of making another, separate file to use a mock batch job to ensure that these records ran, I opted to create a inner class inside of my test class, marked as `@testVisible private`.

However, when trying to use `Type.forName` on this inner class, the function fails and returns a null value. I would expect the `Type` class to be able to access this inner class, as it is executed in a test, and the `private` class is marked `@testVisible`.

Below is a basic example, which fails on my org (CS71):

```
@isTest
public class SomeTypeTest {

    @testVisible
    private class SomeMockType {
        public SomeMockType() {}
    }

    @isTest 
    public static void TypeForName_Test() {
        System.assertNotEquals(null, Type.forName('SomeTypeTest.SomeMockType'));
    }

}
```

The class does execute successfully when marked as `public`, but I'm looking for an answer that describes why `Type.forName(OutClass.InnerClass)` is unable to access the `@testVisible private` inner class, as expected.

Comment: The inner class is called from the outer the class during run time when the class is executed, correct? As you're using a mock, is the type for the mock declared someplace or is it dynamic and dependent on the run time context from the outer class? See where I'm going with my questions?

Comment: The test class this became an issue in was using a inner batch class, setting a custom setting to the name of the inner batch class in a `@testSetup` method, and then calling the class by creating a new instance based on the `Type.forName` result of the custom setting value. I reduced this down to a minimal class to reproduce the issue.

Comment: 1. The inner class is only called by `Type.forName` and nowhere else 2. The type for the mock is declared in a custom setting via a string, 3. Honestly, not really? Shouldn't the running context be a test context?

Comment: Looks like only top level classes can even implement a `batchable` interface, so it looks like this doesn't matter for my test classes, but I'd still be very interested to know why this happens.

Comment: As @sfdcfox said, this is not documented (Salesforce Apex docs are pretty bad in general). But you can get a private type with ```Type.forName(...)``` up to API version 27.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't documented, but it appears that private classes cannot be dynamically retrieved using Type.forName at all. Here's an alternative failing version:

```
public class SomeTypeTest {
    private class SomeMockType {
        public SomeMockType() {}
    }
    public static void TypeForName_Test() {
        System.assertNotEquals(null, Type.forName('SomeTypeTest.SomeMockType'));
    }
}
```

When we call this through executeAnonymous, we receive the same result. Changing "private" to "public" allows Type.forName to find the class.

Type.forName can apparently only access public or global members, regardless of test context or @testVisible being present. I'll ask someone over at salesforce to confirm this, but it looks like you simply can't dynamically access the class, even though you can statically link to them:

```
public class SomeTypeTest {
    private class SomeMockType {
        public SomeMockType() {}
    }
    public static void TypeForName_Test() {
        System.assertNotEquals(null, SomeMockType.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I reported this via the feedback widget on the docs, hopefully someone notices it. @sfdxfox, if you, or anyone else is able to continue this along the chain, I'd appreciate it, but I don't have the connections or the resources to try to notify anyone about this issue, so I'll be accepting this answer- thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I'm just in the process of dragging some older API version classes up to the current release. The test cases for an older class using v23.0 were doing a `Type.forName` that was finding a private inner class defined in a Test using v31.0. Now that both the test class and class being tested are on v43.0 the private inner classes Type can't be found.